# No value given one or more required parameters

Tags: ms-access-2010, vb.net-2010

What's wrong with my code. All i want is that if I click `rdbNormal` (a RadioButton) then select "A" in `cmbBuilding` (a ComboBox), all the RoomNo having roomtype "normal" and building "A" will be displayed.
Here's my code

```
Try
    cn.Open()
    If rdbNormal.Checked = True Then
        Dim DataSet As New DataSet
        Dim DataTable As New DataTable
        Dim DataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM RoomTable Where Building = '" & cmbBuilding.Text & "' and RoomType = Normal ", cn)
        DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)

        If DataTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            With cmbRoomNo
                .Items.Clear()
                For i As Integer = 0 To DataTable.Rows.Count - 1
                    .Items.Add(DataTable.Rows(i).Item(3))
                Next
                .SelectedIndex = -1
            End With
        End If
        DataTable.Dispose()
        DataAdapter.Dispose()
    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
cn.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you have

```sql
... and RoomType = Normal
```

Since `Normal` is not quoted it is being treated like a parameter placeholder. If you want to match the literal value then put quotes around it:

```sql
... and RoomType = 'Normal'
```